# Fallo en la aplicacion al lanzar un intent (action_send)

Tags: android

El problema es que la aplicación me falla al lanzar un `Intent` que sirve para compartir un `ArrayList` de una clase la cual es "Modulo" e implementa la interfaz `Parcelable`. No aparece ningun error en el logcat por lo que quizas lo que creo que puede estar fallando es como lanzo el `Intent` del `ArrayList` del objeto Modulo. Acabo de empezar, y es la primera vez que uso `Parcelable` por lo que si es un fallo muy grande no me lo tengais en cuenta jaja.

Clase "Modulo":

```
public class Modulo implements Parcelable {
    private String nombre;
    private String estado;



    public Modulo(Parcel input){
        nombre=input.readString();
        estado=input.readString();
    }


    public Modulo(String nombre, String estado) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }


    public ArrayList<String> precargarNombres(){
        ArrayList<String> nombresModulos = new ArrayList<>();

        nombresModulos.add("Sistemas de gestión empresarial");
        nombresModulos.add("Programación multimedia y móviles");
        nombresModulos.add("Programación de servicios y procesos");
        nombresModulos.add("Inglés técnico");
        nombresModulos.add("Empresa e iniciativa emprendedora");
        nombresModulos.add("Desarrollo de Interfaces");
        nombresModulos.add("Acceso a datos");

        return nombresModulos;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(nombre);
        dest.writeString(estado);
    }


    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Modulo> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<Modulo>() {
        public Modulo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Modulo(in);
        }

        public Modulo[] newArray(int size) {

            return new Modulo[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Menu donde tengo el boton de compartir:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

            case R.id.compartir:


                Cursor cur = gp.getModulos();
                ArrayList<Modulo> modulos = new ArrayList<>();
                Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                int i=0;

                if(cur!=null & cur.getCount()>0) {
                    for (cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()) {
                        modulos.add(new Modulo(cur.getString(1), cur.getString(2)));
                    }
                }

                for(i=0;i<modulos.size();i++) {
                    Log.d("Modulo ", "Nombre: " + modulos.get(i).getNombre() + " Estado: " + modulos.get(i).getEstado());
                }

                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("MODULOS", modulos);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Compartir"));


                break;
        }


        return true;
    }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar ese proceso mas sencillo te puedo recomendar que implementes la siguiente librería, podría decirse que es el camino fácil para lograr lo que quieres hacer con el camino difícil:

```
implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.12'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.12'
```

Aca la [documentación](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) de la misma.

Es una biblioteca de generación de código, que genera el código fuente de `Android Parcelable` repetitivo.

La implementas de la siguiente manera:

En tu modelo que básicamente debería ser solo esto:

```
public class Modulo {
    private String nombre;
    private String estado;

    public Modulo(String nombre, String estado) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }
```

Basta con agregar la notación `@Parcel` y crear un constructor vacío, el cual esta biblioteca utilizará para realizar el proceso de `parcelable`.

Quedaría similar a esto:

```
    @Parcel
    public class Modulo {
            private String nombre;
            private String estado;

            public Modulo(String nombre, String estado) {
                this.nombre = nombre;
                this.estado = estado;
            }

            public Modulo() {
                //Constructor vacío
            }

            public String getNombre() {
                return nombre;
            }

            public void setNombre(String nombre) {
                this.nombre = nombre;
            }

            public String getEstado() {
                return estado;
            }

            public void setEstado(String estado) {
                this.estado = estado;
            }
```

Ahora para pasar valores solo debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
// Creas un Bundle

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

// usas el metodo putParcelable para agregar el valor dentro del bundle con su respectiva key
// guardas el parcelable que quieres enviar

bundle.putParcelable("INFORMACION", Parcels.wrap(Array));
```

Luego solo queda recibir el mismo donde deseas recibirlo, así:

```
Ejemplo ejemplo = Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("example")); // Desde activity

Ejemplo ejemplo = Parcels.unrap(getArguments().getParcelableExtra("example")); // Desde Fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu código es java puedes descargar el siguiente plugin para Android Studio, lo instalas y reinicias android studio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez reinicies Android Studio posiciona el cursor sobre la clase y puedes tocar Alt + Insertar o bien en Code-->Generate

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparecerá la opción Parcelable en tu clase
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le das en ok y te genera el parcelable:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para pasar un objeto parcelable te dejo un ejemplo sencillo (recordar que si el objeto tiene una propiedad lista esta debe ser también parcelable):

```
//Envias
CustomData data = new CustomData("id", "text");
Intent i = new Intent(this, SegundaActividad.class...);//envias a la actividad
i.putExtra("key", data);

//Recibes 
Intent i = ...; // revisas que el intent contenga la llave "key"
CustomData data = i.getExtras().getParcelable("key");
```

En caso de que sea una lista:

```
//Envias la lista
Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
ArrayList<CustomData> testing = new ArrayList<CustomData>();
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("extraextra", testing);
startActivity(i);


//recibes la lista en la otra actividad:

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//recuerda hacer las validaciones this.getIntent() != null; getIntent().getExtras()!=null; getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("Key") ... todo esto para que no te explote el app con un NullPointerException
    ArrayList<testparcel> testing = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("extraextra");
 }
}
```